# jQuery events not triggering on initial page load

Tags: php, jquery, mouseover, delegation

The following php is outputting various videos on my page with the class name ".videos":

```
<?php
wp_video_shortcode($attr, $content);    
?>
```

The generated code for each video looks like this:

```
<video class="videos" poster="/poster.png" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="/VideoPreview_04.mp4?_=1">
</video>
```

The following jquery is to remove the video controls and make each one play on mouseover and pause on mouseout:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".videos").removeAttr("controls");

    jQuery(".videos").on("mouseover", function(event) {
      this.play();
    }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
      this.pause();
    });
  });
</script>
```

THE PROBLEM:

It all works as it should, EXCEPT, when the page first loads, the mouseover events aren't recognised unless and until you click somewhere on the page first.

I'm sure this has to do with delegation or something like it.
The following for example works when the page is loaded, without clicking somewhere on the page first:

```
jQuery(document).on('focus mouseover', '.videos',  function(e){
  alert("focused on " + jQuery(e.target).attr('id'));
});
```

However, when binding the video to above code, the videos don't react unless again, you click on the page somewhere first.

I've also tried document.focus(); and other ways to give focus on various elements but cannot get it to work.

Help, I'm running out of hair to pull out :(

Comment: if you have more of 1 video in your page it's possible it's the start of the response. Try ton add your event in a loop with each() jQuery(".videos").each(function(){ }); and put all your event in the each function

Comment: did you put your code document ready handler or just before the closing body tag ?

Comment: tried all this, to no avail :( thanks.

Comment: if you force a trigger using jquery to "click" on the page, what does it do?

Comment: not sure how you can do this other than document.focus();

Comment: I've found out that this is only happening if i refresh the page!
If i click the link to the page it doesnt happen.
Weird!

Comment: using http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: WOW! thats an awesome trick!!! Thanks!